# Optimizing my model/view that displays a simple list of items

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I almost finished a backbone.js application, and I am wondering if the methods I choose for displaying tables of items are the correct way to go.

The code I have that displays some items are as follow:

```
var items = new Items();

items.fetch({
    success: function(){
        var itemsView = new ItemsView(items);
        itemsView.$el.appendTo('#content-wrapper');
        // Here I run some functions that
        // remove all elements of the prev page
    }
});

window.Item = Backbone.Model.extend({});

window.Items = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Items,
    url: 'items'
});

window.ItemsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'table',
    id: 'items',
    initialize: function(items) {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.items = items;
        this.items.bind('reset', this.render);
        this.render();
    },
    render: function () {
        var self = this;
        this.items.each(function (item) {
            self.addItem(item);
        });
        return this;
    },
    addItem: function(item) {
        var itemView = new window.ItemView(item);
        this.$el.append(itemView.el);
    }
});

window.ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tr',
    initialize: function (item) {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'serverChange');
        this.item = item;
        // Note that I am using Backbone.IO, it has a slightly 
        // different sync functions to support Socket.IO
        this.item.ioBind('update', this.serverChange, this);
        this.render();
    },
    serverChange: function(data){
        this.item.set(data);
        this.render();
    },
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(_.template('<td><%=name%></td>', this.item.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});
```

### Problem

The problem I am facing is the following. The HTML that is produced by this piece of code is dead ugly.

It created a HTML attribute for each of the variables in my model. It looks something like this:

```
<table id="items">
    <tr name="Awesome Product" id="75483920743829930" _id="75483920743829930" type="gel" price="200.00" stock="5">
        <td>Awesome Product</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is not what I want.

### Why I choose this method

I used this method because every item (`tr`) has it's own view. So when one model changes, it does not need to rerender the whole table, just the one view.

Is there maybe a more elegant way to fix this, without creating messy HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting all those extra properties is because you are passing the model straight into the constructor, rather that passing it in as a model. Backbone is reading the model's attributes and adding them as html attributies to the view.

Usually you pass in the model like this ([Straight from the Backbone docs](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-constructor))

```
var doc = Documents.first();

new DocumentRow({
  model: doc,
  id: "document-row-" + doc.id
});
```

Take a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hqK9d/2/). I have slightly reworked your view to use a model and it now renders without those extra html attribues.

Comment: You are awesome! That fixes the problem. I was about to rewrite the whole app, but it was such a small change. Thanks!